# Using simplehtmldom to grab a text snippet

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to use the simplehtmldom script to get at some text. The HTML structure is as follows

```
<div id="posts">
  <div align="center">
    <SEVERAL LEVELS OF HTML>
      <strong>XXX</strong>
    </SEVERAL LEVELS OF HTML>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <SEVERAL LEVELS OF HTML>
      <strong>IGNORE</strong>
    </SEVERAL LEVELS OF HTML>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <SEVERAL LEVELS OF HTML>
      <strong>IGNORE</strong>
    </SEVERAL LEVELS OF HTML>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text I'm trying to get at is the XXX string, in the first `<strong>` tags inside the first `<div>` with attribute `align="center"`, which is inside the `<div>` with `id="posts"`. I'm not interested in the text in `<div align="center">` tags further down.

The "several levels of HTML" include messy nested tables etc.

My code: I'm using descendant selectors and obviously I'm "skipping" through the several levels of html. Is this the reason why my `print_r` shows `"Trying to get property of non-object"`?

```
$html = file_get_html($page_1);
$es = $html->find('div#posts div[align=center] strong');
print_r($es->plaintext); die;
```

Strangely enough this statement also returns the same `"Trying to get property of non-object"` result. What am I doing wrong?

```
$es = $html->find('div#posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

2 possible reasons :

1. In `$html = file_get_html($page_1);`, `$page_1` may not be a URL. If it's a string containing html use `str_get_html` as in `$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');` instead.
2. The html contains more than one `div#posts` (which shouldn't).